# Java - Draw'ing outside frame

Tags: java, performance, graphics, 2d, game-engine

I am developing a 2d game; I am currently developing a system of movement of the camera on the map, I used the following method: my camera has own coordinates - x,y; 
I have ArrayList with all my sprites for map with their coords from 0 to mapSize, every sprite has a Draw function, which looks simply like

g2d.drawImage(texture, getX(), getY(), getX() + getSizeX(), y + getSizeY(), 0, 0, getSizeX(), getSizeY(), null);

I'm always drawing all my sprites, without checking are they visible or not;
Whether there is a load on the computer at this drawing (when drawing textures that very far away from screen size)? 
Do I need to check whether the object is visible before rendering?

My main DrawAll function contains():

```
public void DrawAll(graphics2D g2d){

    g2d.translate(-playerCamera.getX(), -playerCamera.getY());

    for (int i = 0; i < mapSprites.size(); i++) {
        mapSprites.get(i).Draw(g2d);
    }

    g2d.translate(-playerCamera.getX(), -playerCamera.getY());

    drawSomeStrings, etc....

}
```

This is not very good, because lines that were drawn after second translate may twitch when moving the screen.
Should I give translate up and do the offset coordinates manually in each object\sprite's Draw function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

graphics2D will clip your drawing. So it does not impact too much. If you have a lot of sprites, you should consider using a SpatialIndex to select which Sprite is in the screen. (https://github.com/aled/jsi)

Comment: Thx for information, i will learn more about spatial indexes; but what about using of translate function?